# Completely black screen on startup

Tags: boot, screen, amd-graphics, amd-processor

9 out of 10 times my monitor will stay completely black, no signal, nothing. The monitor just gets a little brighter after I start my pc, and goes back to complete black. Additionally, it sometimes stays black after it went to sleep (worked, idle, went to sleep, stays black). About every 10th time it boots perfectly fine, I see the Asus BIOS menu, then the login, and finally everything is as usual. But the other 9 times the monitor stays black, no TTY, no boot menu, no mather what I click, even with a bootable USB, nothing.

Why it drives me mad / what I tried:

- same setup worked perfectly for 3 months before
- swapped monitor, new monitor works with laptop
- swapped cables, also works with laptop, does not work with pc
- tried another distro (Pop OS)
- booting with / without bootable usb inserted
- upgraded to latest software `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- upgraded BIOS version

Could my graphics card be in a "buggy" state? Is there a tool to check what's wrong? As said, I cannot check if it doesn't work, and if it works everything seems normal.

Please help.

**UPDATE**
Removing the i386 arch (32bit) did not help, even another reinstall of Pop OS. I changed the D.O.C.P. setting from a profile with 2400MHz to 3600MHz, but it does not seem to be the problem. Otherwise everything is the default setting.

I'm using a RX 6900 XT and if the LEDs on the GPU do not light up and the fans do not spin, it does not output a video signal. Also the VGA light on the motherboard is white when it does not work and dark if it does. It seems like a known problem, but nothing helped so far...

- https://linustechtips.com/topic/1326916-ryzen-5800x-with-powercolor-6900-xt-no-display-signal/
- https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/black-screen-no-display-output-6900xt-21-6-2/td-p/480085/page/2
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263042
- search for "rx 6900 xt black screen" / "rx 6900 xt no output"

Some solved it with new drivers, some with new PSUs, some with new monitors, some with new GPUs, ...

Comment: You cleanly installed a different operating system and the problem persists? Then it's probably a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something with the GPU was broken.
Got a new one (same model) a week ago and everything just-works (tm), for now at least. Otherwise no changes were made.